# Change table structure using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to switch a table structure from

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td><div id=1"></div>
   </td>
   <td><div id=2"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

to

```
 <table>
    <tr>
       <td><div id=1"></div>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><div id=2"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

and back to the original structure using JavaScript, would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Why do you have divs in tables? If you didn't you could just float and unfloat them

Comment: Two carousels that I change from vertical to horizontal based on the screen size.  Thanks

Comment: My question remains. Why table? Remove the table and change the CSS to float:left. They will handle the screen themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest you remove the table and simply float the divs as described here

[CSS Floats 101](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101)

```
div { 
  float: left;
}
```

I also suggest you do not use numeric IDs which is allowed in HTML5 but not very compatible and makes JavaScript accessing it potentially confusing

Answer (score 0):

More efficient will be to use method `appendTo`

```
// append new line first
$('table').append('<tr></tr>');

// move td to the new tr
$('table tr td').last().appendTo($('table tr').last());
```

Comment: This is perpetuating the use of tables. OP does not need tables at all

Comment: Agreed actually, I just thought this answer might be useful for him in the future.